# How does the size of memory region argument in read() and write() affect the IO performance?

Tags: c, linux, io

There is [an IO example from Advanced Programming in Unix Environment](https://books.google.com/books?id=kCTMFpEcIOwC&lpg=PA73&ots=zwIERNXxrG&dq=Figure%203.6%20shows%20the%20results%20for%20reading%20a%20516%2C581%2C760-byte%20%EF%AC%81le%2C&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q=Figure%203.6%20shows%20the%20results%20for%20reading%20a%20516,581,760-byte%20%EF%AC%81le,&f=false):

> ```
> #include "apue.h"
> #define BUFFSIZE 4096
> int
> main(void)
> {
>     int  n;
>     char  buf[BUFFSIZE];
>     while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
>     if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n)
>     err_sys("write error");
>     if (n < 0)
>     err_sys("read error");
>     exit(0);
> }
> ```
>
> All normal UNIX system shells provide a way to open a ﬁle for reading
>   on standard input  and  to  create  (or  rewrite)  a  ﬁle  on 
>   standard output, and allows the user to take advantage of the shell’s
>   I/O redirection facilities.
>
> Figure 3.6  shows  the  results  for  reading  a  516,581,760-byte 
>   ﬁle,  using  20 different buffer sizes,  with  standard output
>   redirected  to /dev/null. The  ﬁle  system  used  for  this  test  was
>   the  Linux ext4 ﬁle system  with  4,096-byte  blocks. (The st_blksize
>   value is 4,096.) This accounts for the minimum in the system time
>   occurring at the  few  timing  measurements  starting  around  a
>   BUFFSIZE of  4,096. Increasing  the buffer size beyond this limit has
>   little positive effect.
>
> [image]

1. How does `BUFFSIZE` affect the performance of reading a file?

   As `BUFFSIZE` increases up to 4096, why does the performance
   improve? As `BUFFSIZE` increases above 4096, why does the
   performance have no significant improvement?
2. Does the kernel buffer (not the one `buf` with size `BUFFSIZE` in
   the program) help in the performance, in relation to `BUFFSIZE`?

   When `BUFFSIZE` is small, does the kernel buffer  help to accumulate
   the small  writes, so to improve the performance?

Comment: Hi Tim. We try to reduce chatty material on posts here, in particular thanks, please-help-me, much appreciated, etc. There is [a canonical reference on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/472495).  I normally don't mention it for minor items, but you have 872 of these, so I assume you aren't aware of the linked post. A succinct documentation-style is favoured here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each call to `read()` and `write()` requires a system call (to communicate with the kernel), plus the time to do the actual copying of into to (or from) the kernel's memory space.

The system-call itself imposes a fixed (per-call) overhead/cost, while the cost of copying the data is of course proportional to the amount of data there is to copy.

Therefore, if you `read()`/`write()` very small buffers, the overhead of making the system call will be relatively high compared to the number of bytes of data copied; and since you'll have to make a large number of calls, the overall runtime will be longer than if you had done larger transfers.

Calling `read()`/`write()` a smaller number of times with larger buffers allows the system to amortize the overhead of the system call over a larger number of bytes-per-call, avoiding that inefficiency.  However, at some point as sizes get larger, the system-call overhead becomes completely negligible, and at that point the program's efficiency is governed entirely by the cost of transferring the data, which is determined by the speed of the hardware.  That's why you see performance leveling out as sizes get larger.

`read()` and `write()` do not accumulate small writes together, since they represent direct system calls.  If you want small reads/writes to be buffered that way, the C runtime provides `fread()` and `fwrite()` wrappers that will do that for you inside your process-space.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Why is the levelling size 4,096-byte the block size of the filesystem? (2) "read() and write() do not accumulate small writes together, since they represent direct system calls. If you want small reads/writes to be buffered that way, the C runtime provides fread() and fwrite() wrappers that will do that for you inside your process-space." I meant kernel level buffer, not user space buffer in my post.

Comment: For (1), I don't know -- maybe it's a coincidence, or maybe there's a reason.  For (2), it is the case that the filesystem (and/or your hard drive's internal hardware) will do additional buffering; in particular, `write()` will almost always return before the the bits actually hit the physical disk; however, that buffering doesn't help with the system-call-overhead issue, since every call to `write()` invokes one system call and therefore one system call's worth of CPU cycles, regardless of what happens afterwards.

Comment: When each read/write transfers data smaller than the block size of the filesystem, does it cause more blocks to transfer than when each read/write transfers data bigger than the block size of the filesystem?